I am using vico chart in my android app. Need help in auto scrolling the chart when new data comes in
Hi I am working with https://patrykandpatrick.com/vico/ vico chart in android.
I am using vico chart with jetpack compose. I need help in autoscrolling the chart when new chart values comes up.
I have gone through the source code and can see a class named AutoScrollCondition but could not figure out how to use it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
